# Group by com subdivisões

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um SQL que trás a quantidade de pessoas que se formaram numa determinada data. Digamos que de 300 pessoas, 25 se formaram no dia '2010-06-27'.

Eu gostaria de incluir mais duas colunas que retornem a quantidade de homens e mulheres dessas 25 pessoas que se formaram nesse dia.

```
 SELECT count(*) AS 'quantidade',
 data_nasc,
 (SELECT count(*)
 FROM formandos
 WHERE genero = 'M') AS 'Quant'
 FROM formandos
 GROUP BY data_nasc
 ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Comment: Tem como você mandar a estrutura do banco de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obter a quantidade total de homens e mulheres, faça um sub-select para cada e agrupe pela data.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS 'quantidade',
    F.data_nasc, 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM
            formandos AS H 
        WHERE 
            H.genero = 'M' 
        AND 
            H.data_nasc = F.data_nasc
        GROUP BY F.data_nasc
    ) AS 'Homens', 
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            formandos AS M
        WHERE 
            M.genero = 'F' 
        AND 
            M.data_nasc = F.data_nasc
        GROUP BY M.data_nasc
    ) AS 'Mulheres'
FROM 
    formandos AS F
GROUP BY F.data_nasc
ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Comment: A sua resposta está certa. Só teve um pequeno erro de sintaxe.

Eu retirei o F do Count e do Order by.
Obrigado.

Comment: @fabricio_wm resposta alterada como tua sugestão. :)